# canvasjs live updating data from database

Tags: javascript, web, charts, linechart, canvasjs

I am new to web based visualization tool I used chartjs before but I did not find any solution for chartjs so, I transferred to canvasjs.Now I'm done creating the chart and it is successfully shown, thus I want to make it moving without refreshing because the data from the database is constantly moving. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        $.getJSON("json.php", function(result){
        var dps= [];

//Insert Array Assignment function here
for(var i=0; i<result.length;i++) {
    dps.push({"label":result[i].ts, "y":result[i].ph});
}

//Insert Chart-making function here
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    zoomEnabled:true,
    panEnabled:true,
    animationEnabled:true,
    title:{
        text: "myChart from mySQL database"
    },

    axisX:{
        title: "TimeStamp"
    },

        axisY:{
        title: "myDataPoints",
        minimum: 0
    },

    data: [{
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints:
            dps
              }]
});
chart.render();

});
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

now, I would like to ask for help out there What do I need to keep this chart moving...??

Answer (score 2):

If you want the lines to move, you need to remove dataPoints from the beginning of the array. You can do so using [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) function in JS.

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length;i++) {
    dps.push({"label":result[i].ts, "y":result[i].ph});
    dps.shift();
}
```

This would do the trick for you.

Comment: hai @beevk . thank you so much for the reply I've been waiting for someone to answer. I tried adding the dps.shift() function but nothing happens to mu browser nothing displays. Aside from adding the .shift() function what else must I need to do in order to make is working?

Comment: What do you mean when you say nothing displays? Does it throw some error? Check your console to look for any errors. Also, if you really want to visualize the moving pattern, just for loop isn't going to work for you as you won't be able to see the changes happening. You need to call and read your JSON file with some interval to look for any changes and re-render the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I just change my for loop with the for loop you suggested..